# Submit form data in google sheet in descending order

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am saving form data in a Google Sheets file. I have written code in a bound Apps Script project, and it is working fine.

Now, I want that data in descending order (latest values should come first). For that I have written the code as follows:

```
var headRow = 1;
sheet.insertRowAfter(headRow+1);
sheet.getRange(headRow+1, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);
```

But it is inserting record at the end of the previous record, rather than before it. How can I modify my script to enforce that more recent values come first?

Answer (score 0):

You are using [insertRowAfter](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertrowafterafterposition). As defined,

> Inserts a row after the given row position.

Try to use [insertRowBefore](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertrowbeforebeforeposition) which will function as the reverse of latter.